# Fase de treinamento de RNA - Rede Neural Artificial no Weka

Tags: redes-neurais, weka

Estou desenvolvendo um software que possibilita os usuários criarem novas RNAs.

Ao criar uma nova RNA MultilayerPerceptron no Weka, a fase de testes já é realizada pelas rotinas da lib ou é necessário desenvolver rotinas de treinamento separadamente?

Comment: Poderia reformular sua pergunta? Qual fase de testes você se refere? Ao cálculo dos pesos, taxa de aprendizagem, descida do gradiente...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Teste**

O quinto passo é o teste da rede. Durante esta fase o conjunto de teste é utilizado para determinar a performance da rede com dados que não foram previamente utilizados. A performance da rede, medida nesta fase, é uma boa indicação de sua performance real.

Devem ser considerados ainda outros testes como análise do comportamento da rede utilizando entradas especiais e análise dos pesos atuais da rede, pois se existirem valores muito pequenos, as conexões associadas podem ser consideradas insignificantes e assim serem eliminadas (prunning). De modo inverso, valores substantivamente maiores que os outros poderiam indicar que houve over-training da rede.

http://conteudo.icmc.usp.br/pessoas/andre/research/neural/desenv.htm